# Conditional Layout Blocks in Magento depending if logged in?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What is the easiest/most recommended way to have some conditional layout logic based on if a user is logged or not?

eg.. in pseudocode

```
if (customer logged in)
  display this custom onepage checkout layout block
otherwise
  display this other custom layout block (for guests)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use conditions in your xml file (local.xml, page.xml, etc.). E.g. to add a cms block if customer is logged in:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="name_of_reference_block">
        <block type="cms/block" name="block_name">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>block_id</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

And same logic for logged out customers, e.g. remove a block:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="name_of_reference_block">
        <remove name="name_of_block_to_remove"></remove>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a reference to a controller inside these `customer_logged_in/out` conditional tags? E.g. something like:  `<customer_logged_in><catalog_category_view>(...)</catalog_category_view></customer_logged_in>`

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Magento customer helper in your template:

```
if($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){

//Show block to logged in customers

}else{

// Show different block to guest users

}
```

Alternatively use:

```
Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()
```